# SAPUI5 SmartTable dynamically ignore Columns

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

Is there a way to use the `ignoredFields` property of a sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable to dynamically ignore columns? The value of `ignoredFields` should be changed while the app is running. Is the usage of `ignoredFields` the right way to do this or is there a better way?
I already tried calling the `setIgnoredFields()` function of my SmartTable, but it didn't make any effect on my SmartTable, except when I called it in the `onInit()` function of the respective controller, which of course would defy the dynamic approach i'm looking after.

Comment: You want to dinamically hide colums, right?

Comment: @Cmdd that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to dinamically hide columns in a SmartTable is redefying the columns of the internal Table with all the columns I need and then setting the "visible" property of such columns accordingly.

I still wonder if it is the best solution but is the only one working...

Comment: The problem is, that the columns of mysmarttable are bound to an odata model's entityset, so I can't just redefine them. And just setting the "visible" flag to false probably won't hide the columns from the personalisation dialogue.